Show styles pane in Word for Mac VBA
I have this code to show the styles pane in Word for Windows:
Application.TaskPanes(wdTaskPaneFormatting).Visible = True
Unfortunately this doesn't work in Word for Mac. I can't record a macro (it shows no code).
Can someone please help me with the VBA to show the styles pane in Word for Mac?
Thank you in advance.
Kem

That command hasn't been added to the Word for Mac VBA object model. If it's any comfort, that command doesn't work in Windows either. In testing with Word 365, it just opens the Styles Pane.

Thank you John. That is exactly what I want: open the styles pane. Is there a way to to this on the Mac using VBA?

AFAICS the best you can do is invoke the ToggleStylesPane command, or use Dialogs(1755).Show to do the same. Perhaps someone here knows how to detect whether it is already displayed or not. You might be able to use AppleScript to automate the UI via the Accessibility features on the Mac, but I haven't tried and that requires that the system settings let you use that feature.

I can confirm that Dialogs(1755).Show does display the Styles Pane, as jonsson has suggested.

Thank you both for your answer.
I'm sorry. When I run this code, I get this message.
"This method or property is not available because the command is not available on this platform". But the problem is solved by the answer of Charles Kenyon.

In that case I'd be interested to know which version of Word for Mac you are running, because the CommandBars approach fails (Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument) on every reasonably recent version of Word for Mac I've been able to try it on (2016, the last "2015" version I have) and 2011, whereas the Dialogs(1755).Show works on all of them. Perhaps Word 2004/2001/.X ?)?

I'm running Word for Mac version 16.86 (Office 365).
And I'm running Word for Windows 2019 and 2021.

Thanks - that's actually the same version as I have (on Mac). Oh well, another Word  mystery! Could be down to some Mac security setting I suppose.

Using PowerPoint 2021 version 16.86 (retail edition, not 365), "Application.CommandBars("Styles").Visible=True" fails with a run-time error 5 Invalid procedure call or argument. I hope you're not developing something you expect to run reliably on other Macs.

@jonsson, Yes, another Word mystery. Haha. There are a few.

@John Korchok, I'm not. Thanks for the message though. I'll keep that in mind.

Application.CommandBars("Styles").Visible=True
Not having Word for the Mac, I nevertheless suggest that you try:
Application.CommandBars("Styles").Visible=True


Thank you. Application.Commandbars("Styles").visible=true works fine.
