Macro to close right hand panes in Microsoft Word
I can have up to two separate panes open on the right hand side of my Microsoft Word document – see pink highlighted area in attached. One is styles pane and the other a plugin pane (SmartCite). Is there a macro that can close both these panes simultaneously?
I have tried all of the code lines below and none have worked. All give the error 'Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument'.
Application.CommandBars("Styles").Width = 0

Application.CommandBars("Styles").Visible = False

CommandBars("Styles").Visible = False



There seem to be two different experiences on Mac with CommandBars("Styles"), as you can see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78663236/show-styles-pane-in-word-for-mac-vba . Perhaps it's possible to code for both and catch the exception as needed. As for the JS Add-in task pane, none of the things I have tried worked from VBA on either Mac or Windows . For example, it looks like a task pane,but it isn't one of the standard panes; it's possible to switch to the pane, but that doesn"t help you close it. I hope there is trick I've missed!

For the Styles Pane, all you need is something like:
Sub Demo()
CommandBars("Styles").Visible = False
End Sub

Whether your SmartCite addin can be closed in the same way depends on what it makes accessible to VBA. Check its documentation - or simply use the macro recorder to retrieve whatever VBA can capture of that action.

That code is not working for me. It gives error 'Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument'. I've updated question with other bits of code I have tried. Any other suggestions?

Works for me on a Windows PC running Office 2016. In fact, the code was even produced by the macro recorder!
